# fetch checkbox with checked from linking tabel

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables

```
Products

+---+--------------+
|ID | NAME         |
+---+--------------+
| 1 |Kookboek      |
| 2 |Lotion        |
| 3 |Rijles theorie|
+---+--------------+

Cats
+---+----------+
|ID | CAT      |
+---+----------+
| 1 |Speelgoed |
| 2 |Body      |
| 3 |Boeken    |
| 4 |Verzorging|
+---+----------+

link
+---+---+
|PID|CID|
+---+---+
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
+---+---+
```

How can I do this:

If I fetch the data from **lotion**
The checkboxes are checked from **body** and **verzorging**?

I know INNER JOIN but how build I a correct query?

```
<?php
        $sql = "
            SELECT 
                link.pid,
                GROUP_CONCAT(cats.catname ORDER BY cats.catname SEPARATOR ', ') categories 
            FROM 
                link
            JOIN products ON link.pid = products.id 
            JOIN cats ON link.cid = cats.id
            GROUP BY link.pid
        ";
?>
```

If I fetch product Lotion (2) te record returns **Body, Verzorging** This is ok but I want fetch all categories and body and verzorging checked like this

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="1">Speelgoed</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="2" checked="checked">Body</label>  
<label><input type="checkbox" value="3">Boeken</label>  
<label><input type="checkbox" value="4" checked="checked">Verzorging</label>
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect. SQL does not support checkboxes.

Comment: Hello GMB, I add some details in  my question :)